# removing group by clause with SUM

Tags: sql-server

So lets say I have a table, `MyBigTable` that has student scores of an examination. So lets say the structure looks something like

```
id
name
school 
board
exam_partA_score
exam_partB_score
```

Then I need to run some script on it at certain levels. So lets say I have to run report at the school level so I will have

```
select 
 school, 
 board, 
 cnt_whoPassedA = SUM (CASE WHEN A.exam_PartA_score > 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 cnt_whoPassedB = SUM (CASE WHEN A.exam_PartA_score > 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
from MyBigTable as A
group by A.school, A.board
```

Then I need to run another script at the board level so

```
select 
 school = null, 
 board, 
 cnt_whoPassedA = SUM (CASE WHEN A.exam_PartA_score > 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 cnt_whoPassedB = SUM (CASE WHEN A.exam_PartA_score > 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
from MyBigTable as A
group by A.board
```

Then at the end I need to combine them all so something like

```
select * into BigReport 
from First_Select Statement UNION Second_select_statement
```

Problem:
I have about 6 fields in the group by clause. They change depending on the type of report I need (school level, board level, state level).

I also have about 200 `cnt_*` fields.

Right now I have those "select" statements three times at the different levels which makes my script around 900 lines.

I dont see why I have to compute counts three times when the logic they use is the same all three times. I just need to change the headers (school, board, id..) and the `group by` clause. Not only that, if a spec changes for a count, or another count field is needed then I am going to have to change it in three different places which is very error prone.

What is the best and most efficient way of doing this.

Comment: What do you mean with the *"I have 200 `cnt_*` fields"*? What are these? Calculated columns?

Answer (score 1):

Take your most complex (most GROUP BY columns) then use the OVER clause

```
SELECT
   school, board, col3, col4, ...,
   cnt_whoPassedA, ...,
   SUM(cnt_whoPassedA) OVER (PARTITION BY board) AS cnt_whoPassedA_ByBoard,
   SUM(cnt_whoPassedA) OVER (PARTITION BY school) AS cnt_whoPassedA_BySchool,
   SUM(cnt_whoPassedA) OVER (PARTITION BY school, board) AS cnt_whoPassedA_BySchoolBoard,
   ...
FROM
(
select 
 school, 
 board, 
 col3, col4, ...
 cnt_whoPassedA = SUM (CASE WHEN A.exam_PartA_score > 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 cnt_whoPassedB = SUM (CASE WHEN A.exam_PartA_score > 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
from MyBigTable as A
group by A.school, A.board, A.col3, A.col4...
) T
```

However, I would consider doing this in my report layer (say in SSRS): do you need all levels of grouping at the same time?

Comment: Yes. I beleive a1ex07 has the right idea (though I havn't tried your code and I am not sure what the `PARTITION` is doing, still learning). The problem with a1ex07's idea is that some of the columns change depending on how its grouping by. If I `GROUP BY A, B, C` then my `id = NULL` but if I `GROUP BY A, B` then `id = 100000` **for example**

Answer (score 0):

I believe `GROUP BY ROLLUP (A.board,A.school)` (SQLServer 2005 and up) will work for you. For more complex grouping you may want to use `GROUPING SETS` (2008 and up)

Comment: do you have an example or documentation you might be able to share?

Comment: I think you can start from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx . More examples : http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2011/01/grouping-sets-in-sql-server.html , http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29312/Grouping-Sets-in-T-SQL-SQL-Server-2008

Comment: Hi, the problem is that some of the columns, for example `school` in the original post,  change depending on how its grouped by.